# Latex Error: Cannot determine the size of graphic no bounding box

Tags: graphics, errors

```
\includegraphics[width=1in]{space.jpg}
```

This shows an error:

**Latex Error: Cannot determine the size of graphic no bounding box**

I am new to LaTeX, I learned and installed it in an hour. I need to submit the term paper written in LaTeX by tonight. A kind request, even if you feel like my efforts are inadequate, help me out. I tried my best.

Just tell me the reason of error and how to fix it. I am using MikTeX and TeXnicCenter.

Comment: See the dimensions of the image using the properties of the file (for example: 600px x 250px). Then use the `bb` option passing those values: `\includegraphics[bb=0px 0px 600px 250px, width=1in]{space.jpg}`. This might work.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `pdflatex` and not `latex`?

Comment: I haven't used LaTeX for a long time. But once I solved this problem by adding a bounding rectangle to the picture. It can be made almost invisible.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.